# How to create a property that is enum type

Tags: c#, constructor, enums

```
enum E_Color { red, black };
private E_Color Color
{
    get { return Color; }
    set { Color = value; }
}
public Card(int color, int num)
{
    Color = (E_Color)color;
    Number = num;
}
```

So this is my code and i dont know whats the problem and im pretty sure its here. Im new to c# (i used to program in c++) so i dont know how to do somethings.
when run it in compiles but prints "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException."
if i step into it just stops debuging and finishes when it gets to the constructor.

Comment: If you get an error message, please add it. Otherwise please explain your problem.

Comment: I think that problem is that your property returns itself. It is enough to write: `private E_Color Color { get; set; }`

Comment: Is the problem that you're not sure how to write `public Card(E_Color color, int num)` without getting an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with your enum here. The problem is in your property. You are returning the property itself, which causes an infinite loop (`Stackoverflow`).

Change it to this:

```
private E_Color Color
{
    get; set;
}
```

What you are basically doing is this:

```
private E_Color GetColor()
{
    return GetColor();
}
```

Comment: ok thanks. it worked. should i take down the question?it was kind of dumb.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't, because it has an answer.

Comment: I'd say keep the question, good example of how small things can create weird issues!

Comment: Just leave the question there. Taking it down won't erase it from the past :p