# When set runs "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException."

Tags: c#, accessor

```
private E_Color Color {get; set;}
private int Number
{
    get { return Number; }
    set
    {
        if ((value >= 2) && (value <= 14))
            Number = value;
    }
}
public Card(int color, int num)
{
    Color = (E_Color)color;
    Number = num;
}
```

im pretty sure the problem is with the set in Number but i dont know how to make the get like the one in the Color but make the set so it can only be a number between 2-14.
when i run it in compiles but prints "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.".
when i wrote a line that everytime set runs in prints something it printed it over and over again till it threw the error.

Comment: You need to have a field which you'll use inside your property. At the moment you're calling Number property inside itself and results in `StackOverflowException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah you again. I thought you understand what was wrong [(reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035132/how-to-create-a-property-that-is-enum-type/33035267). You cannot call the properties name inside it's getters or setters. It will cause an infinite loop. You need a backing field.

The problem is in your property. You are returning the property itself, which causes an infinite loop (`Stackoverflow`).

Change it to this:

```
private int num = 0;
private int Number
{
    get { return num; }
    set
    {
        if ((value >= 2) && (value <= 14))
            num = value;
    }
}
```

In your case you will need a backing field, because you are doing some checks before you set the value to `num`.

What you are basically doing (when refering to the properties name inside it's getter or setter) is this:

```
private int GetNumber()
{
    return GetNumber();
}
```

Comment: nowwww i get it. i didnt understand it last time

Comment: Good hehe, I also suggest googling on `properties` and `backing fields`